# First programming language which used "Semi-colon" as a statement separator

Tags: syntax, programming-languages

What is the first programming language which used "Semi-colon" as a statement separator?

Comment: Does the distinction between statement separator (like in Pascal) and statement terminator (like in C) matter?

Comment: Sorry, cannot resist posting a link to the [`Semicolon` programming language](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3854130).

Comment: @svick I was just curious. That's why.. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because History of Programming Languages is off-topic on [SO]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algol 58 was the first programming language to do so.